# Sync 1pps sync with system clock

Tags: timestamps, ntp, ntpd

We need to use 1pps (gpio source) for timestamp in application.

I thought that ntp should be used with the linux pps for this purpose.
But the system is standalone without any other servers connected.
So the question is:

1. Is it possible to do it with ntp without other servers? How ntp.conf should be configured?
2. Does ntp use with pps means that system clock is synced with pps?

If ntp is not the way, is there other method to achieve sync of system clock with pps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to sync via GPS the clock w/o any network connection. You need GPS receiver and antenna on the roof (and usually serial port to connect the receiver)

It is possible to use GSM signal as most of the mobile operators provide also precise clock over signalling channel

Also (as very odd solution) is possible to using D channel of PRI ISDN (if provider have precise time over this channel)

EDIT: You can also buy dedicated time server. Here are few manifacturers (no affiliate with any of them):
[1](https://www.endruntechnologies.com/time-servers.htm), [2](https://www.ntp-time-server.com/ntp-time-server/)

Comment: Is there any example showing how to do it in standalone system? I did not find how to do it.

Comment: @ransh, example about what?

Comment: I mean example how to configure this sync between PPS (gpio source) and system clock. Thx

Comment: @ransh, do we talk about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output ?

Comment: Yes, GPIO used as PPS (pulse-per-second).